# Pandas - How to compare 2 CSV files and output changes

Tags: python, pandas, csv

**Situation**
I have 2 CSVs that are 10k rows by 140 columns that are largely identical and need to identify the differences. The headers are the exact same and the rows are almost the same (100 of 10K might have changed).

**Example**

> File1.csv
>
> ID,FirstName,LastName,Phone1,Phone2,Phone3
> 1,Bob,Jones,5555555555,4444444444,3333333333
> 2,Jim,Hill,2222222222,1111111111,0000000000
>
> File2.csv
>
> ID,FirstName,LastName,Phone1,,Phone2,,Phone3
> 1,Bob, Jones,5555555555,4444455444,3333333333
> 2,Jim, Hill,2222222222,1155111111,0005500000
> 3,Kim, Grant,2173659851,3214569874,3698521471
>
> Outputfile.csv
> ID,FirstName,LastName,Phone1,Phone2,Phone3
> 1,Bob,Jones,5555555555,**4444444444**,3333333333
> 2,Jim,Hill,2222222222,**1111111111**,**0005500000**
> **3**,**Kim**, **Grant**,**2173659851**,**3214569874**,**3698521471**

I think I want the output to be File2.csv with changes from File1.csv highlighted somehow. I'm new to python and pandas and can't seem to figure out where to start. I did my best to search google for something similar to adapt to my needs but the scripts appeared to be to specific to the situation.

If someone knows of an easier/different way, I'm all ears. I don't care how this happens as long as I don't have to check record-by-record.

Comment: Are rows compared by order, or by the ID column? Are the columns guaranteed to be the same between file1 and file2?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Rows are compared by the ID column and the columns will be 100% the same.

Comment: I have posted a general answer. Can you upload the files so that I can be more specific ?

Comment: try this  : https://pypi.org/project/csvdiff/

Answer (score 1):

CSV generally doesn't support different fonts, but here's a solution that uses bold and colors output to the console (note: I only tested on Mac). If you're using Python 3.7+ (dictionaries sorted by insertion order), then the dictionary ordering and columns list shouldn't be necessary.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from csv import DictReader

class Color(object):
    GREEN = '\033[92m'
    RED = '\033[91m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    END = '\033[0m'

def load_csv(file):
    # Index by ID in order, and keep track of the original column order
    with open(file, 'r') as fp:
        reader = DictReader(fp, delimiter=',')
        rows = OrderedDict((r['ID'], r) for r in reader)
        return rows, reader.fieldnames

def print_row(row, cols, color, prefix):
    print(Color.BOLD + color + prefix + ','.join(row[c] for c in cols) + Color.END)

def print_diff(row1, row2, cols):
    row = []
    for col in cols:
        value1 = row1[col]

        if row2[col] != value1:
            row.append(Color.BOLD + Color.GREEN + value1 + Color.END)
        else:
            row.append(value1)

    print(','.join(row))

def diff_csv(file1, file2):

    rows1, cols = load_csv(file1)
    rows2, _ = load_csv(file2)

    for row_id, row1 in rows1.items():

        # Pop the matching ID row
        row2 = rows2.pop(row_id, None)

        # If not in file2, then it was added
        if not row2:
            print_row(row1, cols, Color.GREEN, '+')

        # In both files, print the diff
        else:
            print_diff(row1, row2, cols)

    # Anything remaining from file2 was removed in file1
    for row in rows2.values():
        print_row(row, cols, Color.RED, '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simply by using python's built in CSV library. If you also care about the order of your entries, you can use an OrderedDict to maintain the original file order.

```
import csv
f = []
f3 = file('results.csv', 'w')
with open('file1.csv', 'rb') as f1, open('file2.csv', 'rb') as f2:
    reader1 = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=",")          
    reader2 = csv.reader(f2, delimiter=",")
    for line in enumerate(reader1):
            f.append(line)                        #For the first file, add them all
    for line in enumerate(reader2):
        if not any(e[0] == line[0] for e in f):       #For the second file, only add them if there is not an entry with the same name already
            f.append(line) 
        for e in f:
            if e[0] == line[0]:
                changedindexes = i != j for i, j in zip(e[0], line[0])
                for val in changedindexes:
                    e[val] = e[val] + 'c'                 
c3 = csv.writer(f3, , quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for line in f:                                       #Write the new merged files into another csv
    c3.writerow(line)


#Then find the differences between the two orderedDicts
```

As for bolding, there is no way to do that in CSV, as csv files contain data, not any formatting information.

Comment: Does this compare the file row to row? Because my rows can be different so I want to spit the differences in them. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Yes, each entry in the t1 and t2 orderedDicts will be arrays

Comment: Ok. Honestly, I don't know how to find the differences. I understand I'm supposed to do some of the work so if you could point me towards the right area I'd be happy to look. Before commenting I googled but couldn't find how to compare the arrays and return the difference. What i found was row by row comparison, which won't work.

Comment: ok so I looked at what you wanted, and ill rewrite my code to do what you want, and ill write comments so you can understand it better @ChadBelerique

Comment: Thanks @abhishek, I got it working but I can't tell which rows changed. Is there an indicator or something?

Comment: You can add that in yourself after line 11, put the code 
    'if any(e[0] == line[0] for e in f):
         print (line) .   #This is the old line that was rewritten'

Comment: I really need this to tell me which cell has changed in the row rather than which row changed. Is this possible with your method? I understand you can't format it in CSV but adding something to the changed string would work.

Comment: the code is edited, now it adds a 'c' to the end of every entry that was changed

Answer (score 0):

**A second way:**

```
# get indices of differences
difference_locations = np.where(df1 != df2)
#define reference
changed_from = df1.values[difference_locations]
changed_to = df2.values[difference_locations]

df_differences = pd.DataFrame({'from': changed_from, 'to': changed_to}, index=changed.index)
```